# Can NOT Disable/Enable/Add/Edit any component of the site

Tags: 7, nodes, updating, users

My drupal site is acting strange. I can NOT add/disable/enable/edit any components of the site. I can't add new content types, content fields, disable/Enable modules.

I just removed a module from the drupal server and updated the server cache and drupal cache but the module is listed being listed as 'Enabled' in the Modules List.

How do i fix the issue of my drupal site not accepting any changes?

(P.S. I was able to do a Drupal core update yesterday but that's about it for the changes I can make.)

Comment: What was the Drupal version BEFORE you updated your site? And is it D6 or D7?

Comment: It was Drupal 7 (7.37).  I did upgrade to 7.38 a few days ago. This issue appeared prior to the update.The core updated the modules such as Aggregator, Block, Color, Contact, Contextual links, Database logging, Field, Field SQL storage, Field UI, File, List, Menu, Node etc. 
I tired to disable a Media module today since it requires "Field Entity" cze I thought both could be causing the website issue but no luck. Production site works fine w/o these modules. I also tried removing the Media module from the server, clearing the server cache, drupal cache but the module still appeared 'enabled'.